# Error when making device build:Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, xcodebuild

I am getting this error when making iPad build for device.

**"Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1"**

I searched my blogs and forums and followed steps but no success. Now I deleted all certificate and provisioning profile from keychain and reinstall the latest one but still the same issue. Previously I was using my iOS a/c and now i am using my second iOS A/c certificate. Although when i install the new certificate on another system, it works fine but on my system creating the problem
Please help..

More detail about error...

```
CodeSign build/Debug-iphoneos/base.app
cd /Users/xx/iPad_work/2011/October/my_test/base
setenv PATH "/Developer/ios_sdk_4.2.1/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/ios_sdk_4.2.1/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv _CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_ /Developer/ios_sdk_4.2.1/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: Six sigma (xxxxxxxx)" --resource-rules=/Users/xx/iPad_work/2011/October/my_test/base/build/Debug-iphoneos/base.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/xx/iPad_work/2011/October/my_test/base/build/base.build/Debug-iphoneos/base.build/base.xcent /Users/xx/iPad_work/2011/October/my_test/base/build/Debug-iphoneos/base.app

/Users/xx/iPad_work/2011/October/my_test/base/build/Debug-iphoneos/base.app: object file format invalid or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Thanks